# C++ Is it possible for a structure to accept another structure?

Tags: c++

For example, I am making a linked list structure and I was wondering if it was possible to do something like this:

```
struct linked_list {
     <data structure defined by caller>
     linked_list *next, *previous;
};
```

In the `"<data structure defined by caller>"` area, I was wondering how can I make make another structure in real time and place it in this area?

I don't want to do this:

```
struct A {
...
};
```

I don't want to place A inside of my linked list, I am wondering if its possible to make unique structures in my caller and then have those structures placed inside my link_list file? For example, using one linked_list class to make hundreds of different structures with different data types that all inherit from my linked list?

EDIT: To be more clear, I want something like this:

```
struct Fruit {
    int type;
    struct {
        int size;
        int circumference;
    };
};
```

Except I want to be able to dynamically change all the variables inside the inner structure upon creation.  Is this possible?

Comment: Ever wondered how the standard containers (`std::vector` and friends) achieve this magic?

Comment: @Mat I don't think so.

Comment: Welcome to the world of templates!

Comment: @AlanStokes You "forgot" to say "wonderful" :P

Comment: And what is the practical use of knowing the circumference of a fruit?

Comment: When you say "real time" and "dynamically" do you mean at run time?

Comment: Depending on what "dynamically change" means, you might want to use [`boost::variant`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/variant.html)

Comment: @H2 True! Not to mention "scary", "exciting", "awful" (both senses), "addictive", etc.

Comment: @AlanStokes Fair enough. Maybe add "freaking-out" and "irritating" to the list too. :P

Comment: @remyabel What practical use is worrying about whether a use is practical?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for a template.

```
template <typename T>
struct linked_list {
    T value;
    linked_list *next, *previous;
};
```

Use it like this:

```
struct other_struct {
    int foo;
};

linked_list<other_struct> ll;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear from the question - do you want to mix objects from different types in the list or not. If yes this is a classical polymorphism - you just have to hold a pointer to a base struct instead the struct data itself. If not the H2CO3's answer with templates is a way to go.

**EDIT:** Actually, you may be looking for union. This will allow you to use the same physical memory to represent a different logical information. You can find more about it here: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/other_data_types/